# Jdbc.jdbcstatement connection error from Google Apps Script

Tags: jdbc

We have been utilizing Google Apps Script to access our external Oracle database successfully for the past three years.  From the last 7 days, we have encountered a problem.

error :- Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property executeQuery on object Jdbc.JdbcStatement.
getDataFromOracle

I am successfully connecting database. But I am getting this error while executing the query. Please help me

please help me to provide solution